# Airflow slows down when generating hundreds of DAGs from single python source code

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler, google-cloud-composer

In our Big Data project there are ~3000 tables to load, all of these tables should be processed by a separate DAG in Airflow.

In our solution a single python file generates every type of table loaders so they can be triggered separately via REST API on event-based manner via Cloud Function.
Therefore we generate our DAGs by using:

- Airflow variables used for the DAG generator logic

  - list of table names to generate
  - table type: insert append, truncate load, scd1, scd2
- Airflow variables used by the specific operators of tables loader DAGs, e.g.:

  - RR_TableN = {}  // python dict for operator handling RawToRaw
  - RC_TableN = {}  // python dict for operator handling RawToCuration
- user defined macros:

  - we try not to "static python codes" in between task definitions, because they would be executed during DAG-generation process
  - user defined macros are evaluated only in DAG-execution time

Unfortunately we are bound to version Airflow v1.x.x

**Problem:**

We have noticed that the Airflow/Cloud Composer is signigicantly slower between the task executions when multiple DAGs are generated.
When only 10-20 DAGs are generated the time between the Task executions is much faster then we have 100-200 DAGs.
When 1000 DAGs are generated it takes minutes to start a new task after finishing a preceeding task for a given DAG even when a no other DAGs are executed.

We don't understand why the Task execution times are affected that hard by the number of generated DAGs.
Shouldn't be near constant time for Airflow to search in it's metabase for the required parameters for the TaskInstances?
We are not sure if the Cloud Composer is configured/scaled/managed properly by Google.

**Questions:**

- What's the reason behind this slowdown from Airflow's side?
- How could we reduce the waiting times between the task executions and speed up the whole process?
- Is this a "bad design pattern" what we are implementing (generator and user defined macros processing Airflow variables)?

  - If so, how could we do similar (table separated DAGs, single codebase etc.) in a more effective way?

---

This is a very simple example of the generator code what we use:

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from datetime import datetime

def create_dag(dag_id, schedule, dag_number, default_args):

    def example(*args):
        print('Example DAG: {}'.format(str(dag_number)))

    dag = DAG(dag_id, schedule_interval=schedule, default_args=default_args)

    with dag:
        t1 = PythonOperator(task_id='example', python_callable=example)

    return dag


for dag_number  in range(1, 5000):
    dag_id = 'Example_{}'.format(str(dag_number))
    default_args = {'owner': 'airflow', 'start_date': datetime(2021, 1, 1)}
    globals()[dag_id] = create_dag(dag_id, '@daily', dag_number, default_args)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. That is a known problem. It's been fixed in Airflow 2.

It's inherent to how processing of DAG files were done in Airflow 1 (mainly about the number of queries generated).

Other than migrating to Airflow 2, there is not much you can do. Fixing that required complete refactoring and half-rewriting of Airflow scheduler logic.

One way to mitigiate it - you could potentially, rather than generate all DAGs from single file, split it to many of those. For example rather than generating DAG objects in the single Python file, you could generate 3000 separate, dynamically generated small DAG files. This will scale much better.

However, the good news is that in Airflow 2 this is Many many times faster and scalable. And Airlfow 1.10 reached EOL and is not supported any more and will not receive any more updates. So rather than changing process I'd heartily recommend to migrate.

Comment: Is there any workaround for Airflow 1.x? Unfortunately we are bound to it.

Comment: See updated comment. And tell whoever told you that you are bound to it that they shoudl be afraid ransomware attacks and the like if they stay with Airflow 1.10. See this discussion panel: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=86uqFr3LIc8 . There is never "we are bound to it". There is always "cost of migration vs. cost of not migrating". Cost of not migrating might hit your employer hard. Tell them that.

Comment: use jinja templating to generate those 3K dag files. That seems to be the solution